# Run upload process in background even when phone is asleep

Tags: android, multithreading, service, alarmmanager

So I have developed an android application that determines the user's location every 5 seconds using the fused location (LocationClient), and send this data to my server. This whole process repeats itself every 5 seconds when the app is running. I am uploading the data in background using AsyncTask class.

- **The Problem:**

  Data uploading stops when user closes the app or when the phone is put to sleep.
- **What I want:**

  I want the app to continuously send location data to my server even when the user closes the app or when the phone is asleep. This process should run on a seperate thread as I don't want this process to make my UI thread unresponsive.
- **What I found till now:**

  I have heard of services, intentservices and alarmmanager but I don't know which one to use. I also heard of wakelocks to force the CPU not to sleep. Remember I don't want to keep the screen ON all the time as this will drain the battery.

How can I make my app send data to server all the time ?

Comment: "I don't want to keep the screen ON all the time as this will drain the battery" -- if you cared about the user's battery, you would not be keeping the device running constantly while using stuff like GPS and communicating with a server every 5 seconds.

Comment: AlarmManager is a great solution for running services even when the phone is on sleep. There are plenty of tutorials online...

Comment: @CommonsWare I know my application will drain battery but it would drain even more if kept the phone's display awake all the time. Its a GPS tracking application so I have to keep the internet and GPS awake all the time.

Comment: @longwalker, Do you recommend using AlarmManager for my app ? I don't know how to implement it. A link to any tutorial will help me a lot.

Comment: If the location of the phone does not change significantly, you do not need to upload anything - that would save on tx power.  If the phone is staionary for several 5s periods, you can probably get away with extending the GPS check to longer periods too.

Comment: @Rakesh Yes it is a good choice, but as Martin James suggested, you should update the location only if there is a significant change. Otherwise it would drain your battery. My suggestion is to use implement an algorithm that detects the distance of changed location. This link should help you a lot: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html. Run your background service continuously, and update about the new location only if there is a significant change. Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Here you can create one `Service` and call this service with `AlarmManager` at every 5/10 seconds as per your need...
In your `MainActivity`

```
public static AlarmManager alarm;
    public static PendingIntent pintent;

  // write this code on button click

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);


            pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);


            alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, pintent);

 // button click functionality over


    // write this code outside onCreate()
    protected ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

### MyService

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static int counter = 0;


    public MyService() {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new  Binder() ;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "First Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        counter++;
        Toast.makeText(this, " First Service Started" + "  " + counter,               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    public void onTaskRemoved (Intent rootIntent){

        MainActivity.alarm.cancel(MainActivity.pintent);
        this.stopSelf();
       }
```

Add this to

### manifest

```
 <application
        ....
        <activity
         .....
          </activity>
     <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
      </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a service lunched by your application. It will work in the background , and keep working  until the user close it from the task-manager (if you don't call onDestroy in your code).

Comment: I heard the services freezes when the phone sleeps, that is the code in the service class will not execute when the CPU goes to sleep. How can I make a service execute even when the phone is asleep ?

Comment: I think that the good answer is Anil's one. I mean you use the AlarmManager.
I think you need also this permission

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />